# My profile on Slack for different teams -- am I able to create it only once and use for all teams?

Tags: slack

I wonder, can't I create the main Slack profile as a developer without creating a team which can later be shared to any team I'll be invited to? I want this because each time a new team sends me an invite, I have to register all over again, although it's still the same  Slack website.

https://slack.com/

Answer (score 3):

No. You Slack user and profile is always part of the individual Slack team / workspace. Slack does not support global users.

As I understand that is part of Slack's security architecture, where it's not possible to see other Slack teams unless you have been explicitly invited.